# VB error "Conversion from string "O" to type 'Double' is not valid." On a noughts and cross's game

Tags: vb.net

```
'array format

Dim Array(2,2) as string


'to input where you want to go
  Dim i, j As Integer

        i = InputBox("Enter the left hand co-ordinate:")
        j = InputBox("Enter the right hand co-ordinate:")

        Array(i, j) = "X"
        Call DisplayInput()
        Call CheckWinB()



'to check win
 
If Array(0, 0 = "O") And Array(0, 1 = "O") And Array(0, 2 = "O") Then
            MsgBox("Player A, you win!")
        End If
```

Answer (score 1):

Move the equality check outside of the array indexer.

```
If Array(0, 0) = "O" And Array(0, 1) = "O" And Array(0, 2) = "O" Then
    MsgBox("Player A, you win!") 
End If
```

Comment: Sorry mate i dont know what you mean

Comment: @TomH Your code has: `Array(0, 0 = "O")` instead of `Array(0, 0) = "O"`. VB.NET's *evil type-coercion* tries to convert `"O"` to a number to compute `0 = "O"`, then convert that `Boolean` back to a number as the array index, then convert the array value to a `Boolean` for the `If` condition.

Comment: So how would i put that into code to allow it

Comment: @TomH Precisely as I showed you in my answer: use `Array(0, 0) = "O"`, *NOT* `Array(0, 0 = "O")`!

Comment: I literally put Array(0,0) = "O" ?

Comment: @TomH Yes, as I showed you in my answer.